# How to call and define a variable in a method in another (imported) middleware class?

Tags: python, django, session, django-channels

I'm working on a pet project on django1.10 experimenting with channels. I have a Middleware and i want to import and hook it into myapp.I want the 'ip', 'user_agent' ,'session_key' parameters from the middleware to hook to my channel/sessions.py. As i'm still grasping python and django, i appreciate any help on how to hook my middleware class SessionMiddleware to my channels/sessions.py.

The relevant code for the middleware is:

```
class SessionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Middleware that provides ip and user_agent to the session store.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, None)
        request.session = engine.SessionStore(
            ip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', ''),
            user_agent=request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', ''),
            session_key=session_key
        )
```

The channels/sessions.py is:

```
def inner(message, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure there's NOT a http_session already
        if hasattr(message, "http_session"):
            return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            # We want to parse the WebSocket (or similar HTTP-lite) message
            # to get cookies and GET, but we need to add in a few things that
            # might not have been there.
            if "method" not in message.content:
                message.content['method'] = "FAKE"
            request = AsgiRequest(message)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError("Cannot parse HTTP message - are you sure this is a HTTP consumer? %s" % e)
        # Make sure there's a session key
        session_key = request.GET.get("session_key", None)

        if session_key is None:
            session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, None)
        # Make a session storage

        if session_key:
            session_engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
            session = session_engine.SessionStore(session_key=session_key,user_agent=user_agent,ip=ip)
        else:
            session = None
        message.http_session = session
        # Run the consumer
        result = func(message, *args, **kwargs)
        # Persist session if needed (won't be saved if error happens)
        if session is not None and session.modified:
            session.save()
        return result
    return inner
```

The question may be trivial, needing understanding of basic python class/function import.I was able to import the module and class SessionMiddleware;I tried to define 'ip','user_agent',and 'session_key' as global variables in the channels/sessions.py(probably missing something because i get an error):

> NameError:name 'user_agent' is not defined.

` when i try to assign 'session'in the if statement in the #Make a session storage in channels/sessions.py:

> session =session_engine.SessionStore(session_key=session_key,user_agent=user_agent,ip=ip)

I am having difficulty in understanding the following:
1. What is the pythonic way to call 'ip','user_agent' and 'session_key' parameters to my channels/sessions.py.
2. How can i make these parameters to have a global scope in channels/sessions.py.

Comment: Please share the code and flow with us for a better solution. Where are you using this line in code 'session =session_engine.SessionStore(session_key=session_key,user_agent=user_agent,ip=ip)' Please share both code snippets.Your middleware class and sessions.py code.